# How to log every "throw" in node.js program?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I have a quite large js codebase that is run as node.js script. I'd like to log every exception even if it is caught inside the production code.

Is it possible to achieve? I thought about injecting some code inside `Error` constructor by redefining it, but some parts of code throw custom errors. Redefining all error types from the production code is not feasible, neither is adding logging logic next to every throw statement and/or try-catch block.

The best solution would be to somehow redefine throw keyword - is that possible?

Comment: i think the best thing would be to make it part of your culture that happens automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to log and trace NodeJS Events and Event handlers invocation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655848/how-to-log-and-trace-nodejs-events-and-event-handlers-invocation)

Answer (score 1):

There is an [event for unhandled exceptions](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception):

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log('Caught exception: ' + err);
});
```

Comment: I know, but it doesn't solve my problem. I'd need an event for ALL exceptions, even caught ones.

Comment: @rubix_addict I'm not sure such event exists. You'll have to rethrow in all your `catch`.